# jquery icons not showing up?

Tags: jquery, html, icons

I'm following a tutorial on jquery icons here: http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/icons/index.php

when I do stuff like `data-icon="delete"` or `data-icon="check"` the icons show up just fine, but when I do `data-icon="ui-icon-caret-l"` or `data-icon="ui-icon-home"`

my icon doesn't show up at all, why is this?

[image]

the button on the left is using ui-icon-caret-l and the one of the right is using check, how do I get icons like ui-icon-caret-l and ui-icon-home to show up?

Comment: about console errors?

Comment: I checked with F12 and there is absolutely nothing in the console

Comment: are you sure you've embed all required jquery ui css, js, fonts files.

Comment: Show the CSS you have linked

Comment: I am not using css this is all html and jquery

Answer (score 1):

Jquery automatically converts the value of the data-icon attribute to a ui class name.

For example, if you write this:

```
[code]<a href="#" data-icon="carat-l"></a>[/code]
```

When jquery is parsing the html page, then the above html is converted  into this:

```
[code]<a href="#" style="ui-icon-carat-l"></a>[/code]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it seems like the icon names in the tutorial were simply incorrect, I tried carat-l instead of ui-icon-caret-l like the tutorial said and the icon showed up just fine.